# Mysql unique key does not work

Tags: mysql

here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `loan_table` (
 `ID` bigint(38) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `LOAN_ID` bigint(38) DEFAULT NULL,
 `PLAN_ID` bigint(38) NOT NULL,
 `EXT_LOAN_APP_ID` bigint(38) DEFAULT NULL,
 `REDISTRIBUTE_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `IDX_UN_LOAN_PLAN_APP`(`LOAN_ID`,`PLAN_ID`,`EXT_LOAN_APP_ID`,`REDISTRIBUTE_TIME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I add unique key on 4 columns (LOAN_ID,PLAN_ID,EXT_LOAN_APP_ID,REDISTRIBUTE_TIME), but I can execute  below insert sql again and again.

```
INSERT INTO `loan_table` (`LOAN_ID`, `PLAN_ID`,`EXT_LOAN_APP_ID`, `REDISTRIBUTE_TIME`)
VALUES
( 435870, 0,  2369, NULL);
```

Comment: Of course you can. `null` is a special value. There's no problem here, it works as expected, you just haven't read the docs properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an unique index,mysql treats NULL as an unique value.So these values can be inserted repeatedly

```
( 435870, 0,  2369, NULL);
```

Make the columns NOT NULL and DEFAULT to empty string.

Comment: What if I have foreing key and can't insert an empty string?

Comment: Then you db design is off.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean if you need to insert nulls into a foreign key column your database design is probably  not correct,you shouldn't need to insert nulls into a foreign key.